# XCode 3.2.4 Project - no "other linker flags" in build settings visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, build, openfeint

I am recently trying to connect my cocos2d game with open feint, but I can't accomplish it as there seem to be some settings missing in my build settings of any project that I create.

For example, I have to check "Call c++ Default ctors/Dtors in objective c", but there isn't such an option in my build settings. What's wrong with that?

Here is a picture:
http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/3425/bildschirmfoto20101023u.png

My project is the one on the left, I downloaded the right one. I need to my build settings to like like the ones on the right. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the image, you have the build settings windows set to show "settings defined at this level".  Since you haven't yet changed the other linker flags setting, naturally it doesn't show up.  If you show all settings, you should see it.

Comment: I tried EVERYTHING instead of scrolling down in the build settings where all the other options showed up. urgs. You are my hero, thank you very much! :)